# libtorch/Pytorch: Slicing channels from Tensor in C++

Tags: c++, deep-learning, pytorch, opencv3.0, libtorch

I have a neural network for a segmentation task which produces an output tensor ofshape [1, 2, 416, 416]. The first index is the batch size, the second is the output channel. I can get rid of the the batch dimension by using squeeze(). I can reduce the two channels to one by using argmax(0) after squeeze() but I'd like to know how to get the channels separatly.

Here's a snipped of the code I'm currently using to convert the tensor to a cv::mat:

```
tensor = tensor.squeeze().argmax(0).detach(); //instead of argmax get specific channel.
std::cout << tensor.sizes() << std::endl;
tensor = tensor.contiguous();
tensor = tensor.mul(255).clamp(0, 255).to(torch::kU8);
tensor = tensor.to(torch::kCPU);
int64_t height = tensor.size(0);
int64_t width = tensor.size(1);
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC1, tensor.data_ptr());
```

I'm currently using PyTorch/libtorch 1.2 because it's the latest version compatible with VS2015.

Comment: Does simple indexing like `tensor[0]` and `tensor[1]` not work after squeeze?